# Downloading file with UTF-8 (Thai language) filename in ASP.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have create a function that use to download a file and it's work properly except filename. When I download a file with Thai language name, its name turns into html entities.

For example:

- Original filename: `ไฟล์_1_ข้อมูลลูกค้า__Customer_Information_.xml`
- Saved filename: `"&#xE44;&#xE1F;&#xE25;&#xE4C;_1_&#xE02;&#xE49;&#xE2D;&#xE21;&#xE39;&#xE25;&#xE25;&#xE39;&#xE01;&#xE04;&#xE49;&#xE32;__Customer_Information_.xml".`

How can I save the file with an original name? Here is my code:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadOtherFile(string id, string filename)
{
    string trueFileName = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(filename);

    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", filename);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(option.ApiBaseUrl)
    };
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("token"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/file/other/job/" + id + "/" + trueFileName);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return File(content, "APPLICATION/octet-stream", trueFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //error
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Non-Latin characters should be encoded. Header values can't contain non-Latin characters. Browsers recognize the encoded strings. Do you have a problem with the client?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't the filename parameter you pass from the *client*? Was it double-encoded perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have just checked client-side page that my friend has written then I found that he use another variable to set the filename so however I try to change the filename it doesn't change at all. Sorry for having troubled you. One last question, you have told me that it's a problem with the client, is it ok to mark your answer as an accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, and not only because it's my answer. Knowing that something can't be reproduced lets you move on to other possible causes. I added another update on easy ways to investigate such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, header values accept only ISO-8859-1 characters so [non-ASCII characters are always encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-6). The client should be able to recognize the encoding. If it doesn't, it's a problem with the client. ASP.NET Core *does* follow the standard as [the source code shows](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/aa89639d629899985b27b4ad749f707efc8892cd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileResultExecutorBase.cs#L124).

The [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header doesn't accept a filename. The filename is specified in the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header.

The correct way to return a file with a specific name is to use the [File(Stream,string,string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_) method, or pass the file name as part of the `Content-Disposition` header.

You should replace:

```
return File(content, "APPLICATION/octet-stream, trueFileName");
```

with :

```
return File(content, "application/octet-stream", trueFileName);
```

**Update**

I can't reproduce any problem. I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC application whose `Home/Index` method is just :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var trueFileName = "ไฟล์_1_ข้อมูลลูกค้า__Customer_Information_.xml";
    var bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");
    return File(bytes, "APPLICATION/octet-stream", trueFileName);            
}
```

Browsing to that URL downloaded a file whose name is

```
ไฟล์_1_ข้อมูลลูกค้า__Customer_Information_.xml
```

I tested this with Chrome, Firefox and Edge Chromium.

The name wasn't HTML encoded, it was percent-encoded the way it should be. The raw HTTP response was :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019 15:13:54 GMT
Content-Type: APPLICATION/octet-stream
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=_____1_______________Customer_Information_.xml; filename*=UTF-8''%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%9F%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%8C_1_%E0%B8%82%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%84%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2__Customer_Information_.xml

Hello
```

**Update 2**

The filename is passed from the client as a URL parameter and is probably encoded twice. That's the only way `HtmlDecode` would produce another HTML encoded string.

This call :

```
var fileName="&#xE44;&#xE1F;&#xE25;&#xE4C;_1_&#xE02;&#xE49;&#xE2D;&#xE21;&#xE39;&#xE25;&#xE25;&#xE39;&#xE01;&#xE04;&#xE49;&#xE32;__Customer_Information_.xml";
var actualName=HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(fileName);
```

Returns  :

```
ไฟล์_1_ข้อมูลลูกค้า__Customer_Information_.xml
```

I suspect the string was encoded twice.

To troubleshoot such problems a quick first step is to use a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture and inspect HTTP requests and responses on the fly. This doesn't require any changes on the server or client.

A similar tool is the `Network` tab in the Developer Tools of all modern browsers.

Another option is to change the web application's logging configuration to log the requests and responses. This should only be done during testing or investigating issues though, as it produces a *lot* of text and slows down the application

Comment: My bad, I type my code incorrectly. But again my result is same as I ask in the question.

Comment: @Akethanut encoding the filename is part the standard. Header values can't contain non-Latin characters. Browsers should recognize the encoded names.

Comment: Well, I have tried different browser and different machine but the result is still the same. Do you have any idea to track the problem or any other solutions to write downloading file code?

Comment: @Akethanut I can't reproduce any problem. When I return a file with that name, the browser downloads a file with that exact name